How can I see Orion's Belt in winter and summer?
How can the 23 degree tilt of the Earth enable someone in Argentina to see the same constellation (Orion's Belt) in winter as someone in Britain in summer?

Isn't this just a geometry question? Have you tried to picture a celestial sphere centred on a tilted earth with a constellation not very far from the celestial equator?

Your question is unclear. Are you asking how the tilt of the axis causes the seasons? Or why the seasons in the southern hemisphere are opposite to the seasons in the northern hemisphere?

This seems to be more about proving flat Earth wrong (or right ?) and I regard that as covered by our "no personal theories" rule.

Your field of view is an entire hemisphere of the celestial sphere, so the celestial equator can be seen from all latitudes. The rest is just a matter of the direction of night, which depends directly on the time of year.

Videos on flat Earth ideas are an example of the strangeness of human psychology not physics.

Voting to reopen. He talks about what flat Earthers say. He talks about what other people say. A model where the Earth orbits the Sun refutes the flat Earthers. He wants to understand this refutation.

This page by mathematician / artist Jos Leys: Flat Earth Nonsense has some great info & videos debunking Flat Earth. But don't expect that you'll be able to convince them of anything.

@mmesser314 Flat earth is not mainstream physics.

@VincentThacker The reference to flat earth is irrelevant. The actual question concerns astronomy in the globe Earth/heliocentric model, so is entirely mainstream science. I have also voted to reopen.

Danny - we do see different constellations in winter and in summer and a heliocentric model of the solar system entirely explains this. You do realise that winter in Britain is the same time of year as summer in Argentina, right ?

@gandalf61 If everything in the question were removed except the last sentence, then it will be on-topic.

@VincentThacker Done.

@gandalf61 OP might be referring to seasons in the northern hemisphere. The season names are commonly used to refer to the time of year as well, in which case they follow the northern hemisphere.

The constellation of Orion straddles the celestial equator, so it can be seen from both northern and southern hemispheres at the right time of year. As the Wikipedia article on Orion says:

Orion is most visible in the evening sky from January to April, winter in the Northern Hemisphere, and summer in the Southern Hemisphere ... In the period May–July (summer in the Northern Hemisphere, winter in the Southern Hemisphere), Orion is in the daytime sky and thus invisible at most latitudes ... In countries close to the equator (e.g., Kenya, Indonesia, Colombia, Ecuador), Orion appears overhead in December around midnight and in the February evening sky.

